# How can I keep playing the UILocalNotification sound until user dismiss it?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uilocalnotification

As titled, I use `UILocalNotification` for alarm purposes. But the sound is only played once.

I would like to keep the sound playing until user dismisses the notification. Is that possible?

Please post some sample code if that's possible.

Multiple notification certainly can do it, but I want to keep the notification center neat.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `fireDate` to that specific time and set the `repeatInterval` to `NSDayCalendarUnit` and schedule the alert with `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification: myNotification];`

Comment: That doesn't answer his question though,read the question again. He is able to schedule the notification, but he wants to play the sound until user dismisses the notification.

Comment: It does. All he needs to do is to repeat the notification and remove the notification once the user dismisses it.

Comment: So, you think he needs to annoy the users device with repeated notifications until user gives attention to atleast one of the notification.

Comment: That is what he wanted to do ... That might be his intent too ... He'll probably use this for an alarm app ...

Comment: Repeated notifications certainly can do, but they leave to many items in notification center. Is there any way to keep notification center neat?(only one item displayed in notification center)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a repeat interval with one minute. And then have a sound to play for 30 seconds. There will be of course 30 seconds of silence before the alarm goes on again.

Comment: how about a repeat interval with one sec?

Comment: That could work too. I have only tried with minute repeat interval.

Comment: Repeated notifications certainly can do, but they leave too many items in notification center. Is there any way to keep notification center neat?(only one item displayed in notification center)

Comment: At least not what I'm aware off. The only way to remove the notifications from the notification center is to cancel the notification (inside the app).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As I assumed, the app only fires one notification( thus in notification center only one items showed), and plays sound endlessly... but how to play sound endlessly is still a big problem